# AngularJS ng-repeat colspan rowspan issue

Tags: angularjs, html-table, col

```
<table border=1>
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Status</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Gender</th>          
   </tr>
 </thead>    
 <tbody ng-repeat="group in groups">
   <tr>
     <td rowspan="3">{{group.name}}</td>  
     <td rowspan="3">{{group.status}}</td>        
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="member in group.members">
     <td>{{ member.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ member.gender }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code gives the output as below:

[image]

I need to make the `Status` column the 4th column instead of the current 2nd i.e appear after the `Gender` column. I tried using ng-repeat-start by adding one more `tr` having the status `td` but it comes as another row

[JS-Bin](http://jsbin.com/wakuludopo/2/) for the same

Comment: If you absolutely need to keep table tag, likely easiest to create a directive to generate the  html yourself. Otherwise might consider using a `<div>` structure which would be easier to construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-if` checking the `$index` using modulo (`%`) for the columns with a `rowspan` might do the trick: [jsbin.com/jaxuvavaba](http://jsbin.com/jaxuvavaba/1/edit?html,js,output)